# Nodemailer doesn't work from mobile phone

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I developed a web app in nodejs where I submit a form with inputs and send them to email. I used nodemailer for sending data to email. Here is my app.js code:

```
     var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "email1@gmail.com",
        pass: "password"
    }
});
     app.get('/api', function(req, res) {

        var mailOptions = {
           from: 'email1@gmail.com', 
           to: 'email1@gmail.com', 
           subject: 'Subjest',
           text: 'test text'
       };
       console.log(mailOptions);
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
         if(error){
                console.log(error);
            res.end("error");
         }else{
                console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            res.end("sent");
             } 
        });
    });
```

It does work fine when I submit the form from laptop/pc but if I submit from mobile devices (I checked from iphone), the submit button redirects to an email account (which account is default set in email app of the device) with query string like this:

```
input1=testdata&input2=testdata&submit=submit
```

Any suggestion why the form is being submitted from PC but it's being redirected to email account with query string? Thanks in advance.

Nodemailer version v0.7.1,
Node.js version v4.6.0

**UPDATE:**

In client side, I've `<form action="mailto:email1@gmail.com"></form>`; If I delete the action attribute, then still I can send the email from PC but from mobile device, this time I get the following error:

```
Cannot POST /abc.html
```

Comment: You didn't mentioned one major detail: What are you using on mobile for sending the email ? Have you tested on pc from an anonymous tab ?

Comment: @Marcs, I tested in safari and google chrome from iPhone 5. and email account is gmail. Did you mean private/incognito mode by anonymous tab? Yes, I tested in private/incognito mode on PC.

Comment: Sounds very much like your client side is broken, not the server side. How exactly are you calling `/api`?

Comment: @robertklep,   $.getJSON('[url]http://localhost:8081/api',   formData, callback);

Comment: @robertklep, after url, this is closing single quote not semicolon. For some reason, it's getting semicolon instead of closing single quote.

Comment: @JoeZ are you canceling the submit event of the form in the clientside code? If not, the form will be submitted, which may be the cause for the e-mail account being opened.

Comment: @robertklep, In client side, I've <form action="email1@gmail.com"></form>; If I delete the action attribute, then still I can send the email from PC but from mobile device, this time I get the following error:

Cannot POST /abc.html . I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeZ this is a client-side problem, not a server-side problem. You should add the code that you're using to handle the form to your question.